# laravel 5.2 relation not working

Tags: php, laravel-5

Laravel 5.2 installed using composer. I have 2 tables customers with id and name also orders with id, customer_id and name. Created 2 model Customer and Order.
Order model

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Order extends Model
{
    //
    protected $table = 'orders';
    public function customer(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Customer'); 
    }
}
```

in the root file

```
Route::get('orders',function(){
    $orders=App\Order::find(1);
    echo "<pre>";
    foreach($orders as $order){
        echo $order->name."Order by ".$order->customer->name."<br />";
    }
});
```

It show error
Trying to get property of non-object

Comment: Since your call find() on Order class, what you get is simply an Order object. You should just echo $orders->name and $orders->customer->name

Answer (score 0):

You are not adding customer entries in your function. To do so do the following:

```
Route::get('orders',function(){
    $orders=App\Order::find(1)->customer();// this will add customer entries to your order
    echo "<pre>";
    foreach($orders as $order){
        echo $order->name."Order by ".$order->customer->name."<br />";
    }
});
```

### Update:

```
Route::get('orders',function(){
        $orders=App\Order::with('customer')->all()->get();// add with()
        echo "<pre>";
        foreach($orders as $order){
            echo $order->name."Order by ".$order->customer->name."<br />";
        }
    });
```

Comment: How to execute App\Order::all()->customer()

Answer (score 0):

Jest install composer using

```
composer install
```

in composer

Comment: could you explain your answer ?